# When is "DOMNodeInserted" event called?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, dom-node

`DOMNodeInserted` event is called when the node "be appended to", or "be appended"?

I ask this because the following code:

```
function AddTextToContainer () {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode ("My text");
    var container = document.getElementById ("container");

    if (container.addEventListener) {
        container.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInserted', OnNodeInserted, false);
    }
    container.appendChild (textNode);
}
```

and that:

```
function AddTextToContainer () {
   var textNode = document.createTextNode ("My text");
   var container = document.getElementById ("container");

   if (textNode.addEventListener) {
       textNode.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInserted', OnNodeInserted, false);
   }
   container.appendChild (textNode);
}
```

**Both** invoke `OnNodeInserted` in Chrome. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)

> ```
> DOMNodeInserted
> Fired when a node has been added as a child of another node. 
> This event is dispatched after the insertion has taken place. 
> The target of this event is the node being inserted.
> Bubbles: Yes
> Cancelable: No
> Context Info: relatedNode holds the parent node
> ```

The key is the **Bubbles: Yes** - thats why its being fired on the container as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent the event from bubbling up just use event.stopPropagation(); in your text node callback. Events are then no longer handled up the dom tree.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't seem to have any effect for me. The event is still firing for children of the target. I have worked around it by checking that `event.target` is the object I think it is.